# Как сделать правильный вид?

Tags: php

Как сделать, чтобы при отправлении не выходил сам php код и заметьте, я работаю на денвере. Все равно

```
<?php
echo "Привет, $_GET['name']  Вам $_GET['age'] лет ";
?>
```

Второй файл

```
<html><body>
<form action="lost.php" method="post">
Введите имя: <input type=text name="name"><br>
Введите возраст: <input type=text name="age"><br>
<input type=submit value="GO!">
</form>
</body></html>
```

Вот в чем дело: когда отправляю форму, нажимаю отправить, то выходит сам php код.

Comment: Расширение файлов какое?)

Comment: @bekzat, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй без кавычек выводить переменные

```
<?php echo "Привет, ".$_GET['name']."  Вам ".$_GET['age']." лет "; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
echo "Привет, $_GET[name]  Вам $_GET[age] лет ";

?>
<?php
```

echo "Привет, ".$_GET['name']."  Вам ".$_GET['age']." лет ";
?>

Если при открытии он и <?php выводит, то смотри настройки